How is Apple's new Privacy Manifest different than App Privacy Details in App Store Connect?
Apple is instating a new requirement to include a privacy manifest file in your app by May 1st, 2024. I'm curious if anyone knows how this differs from the App Privacy details that you are required to fill out before submitting an app on App Store Connect? It seems like there is overlap between the two, are they both required? I'm a bit confused if anyone can help clarify, thanks!


There are parts that overlap, and while I don't believe that Apple has said so, it's quite possible that at some point the manifest will be the single source of truth for privacy information.
That being said, the manifest has two things going for it that the privacy details do not:

Third-party frameworks are required to provide their own manifests, which may exposed privacy details that you were unaware of, and will be useful when you fill out your privacy report card.
The privacy manifest also has a section for reporting on privacy-sensitive APIs that do not have an analog in the privacy details section on App Store Connect.

So you currently need to do both, especially if you're using any privacy-sensitive APIs. At some time in the future, it is possible that you will only need to do the manifest and the privacy reporting at App Store Connect will go away.
